# How do I print an array multiple times?

Tags: java, arrays, random

My following code is mostly somebody else's, I was able to figure out how to print the correct range, but now I want to print that range (array) multiple times.

```
    public class lottery {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] lottery = new int[6];
    int randomNum;

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        randomNum = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random() * 59); // Random number created here.
        for (int x = 0; x < i; x++) {
            if (lottery[x] == randomNum) // Here, code checks if same random number generated before.
            {
                randomNum = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random() * 59);// If random number is same, another number generated.
                x = -1; // restart the loop
            }

        }
        lottery[i] = randomNum;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < lottery.length; i++)
        System.out.print(lottery[i] + " ");

    }    
}
```

The output, as expected is six integers in a row:

```
12 52 46 22 7 33
```

I have unfortunately not been able to find anything directly relevant to my question. I am an absolute Java beginner, so please be gentle.

The output I want is as follows, where each x is a random number.

```
    x x x x x x
    x x x x x x
    x x x x x x
    x x x x x x
    x x x x x x
```

Technically, I'd like for the last number to be a random number, but a smaller range. I'll burn that bridge another time.

Comment: So you want to print 6 non repetitive random number between 0-59?? Is that your question??

Comment: What about `System.out.println( java.util.Arrays.toString( lottery ) );`

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
for(int j = 0; j< numberOfTimeToPrint; j++)
   {
   for (int i = 0; i < lottery.length; i++)
       System.out.print(lottery[i] + " ");
   System.out.print("\n\n"); // 2 line feeds, 1 to terminate the line and another for a blank
   }
```

Comment: This seems to be what I'm looking for. Can you tell me how to insert a line break between each iteration of a for loop? :)

Comment: @Brad Newland: two ways: `System.out.println("");` or `System.out.print("/n");`.  Or simply replace that function call with println().

Comment: As Ron Thompson pointed out, there are  many ways to do it. I modified my sample to add a linefeed after each set.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < lottery.length * howManyToPrint; i++){
    System.out.print(lottery[i] + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this. You can use scanner to input the number of times yu require.

```
 public class lottery {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int noTimes = 7;


        for (int j = 0; j < noTimes; j++) {
            int[] lottery = getRand();
            for (int i = 0; i < lottery.length; i++) {
                System.out.print(lottery[i] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
    }

    public int[] getRand() {
        int[] lottery = new int[6];
        int randomNum;
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            randomNum = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random() * 59); // Random number created here.
            for (int x = 0; x < i; x++) {
                if (lottery[x] == randomNum) // Here, code checks if same random number generated before.
                {
                    randomNum = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random() * 59);// If random number is same, another number generated.
                    x = -1; // restart the loop
                }

            }
            lottery[i] = randomNum;
        }

        return lottery;
    }
}
```

Comment: When I make int noTimes larger than the array is (6) I get exception errors. (Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6) To be exact.
When I make it less, 5 for example, the program compiles and runs fine, but still only prints the array one time.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment please, I misread. This does what I want, but I was expecting that new line to break each iteration of the loop. So each 6 random numbers would be a new line.

Comment: So it means you want new array in each iteration of loop? If yes please respond, I will post it for you.

Comment: Yes. And each iteration on new line. Thank you very much for your help thus far!